# Как поэлементно извлечь значения из QtCore.QPointF

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Извлекаю данные

```
line_serieG.append(QtCore.QPointF(self.min, z))
line_serieG.append(QtCore.QPointF(self.max + 1, z))

vectorG = line_serieG
zn = vectorG.pointsVector()

print(zn[0])
```

данные получаются такие:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QPointF(1.0, 1.835)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPointF(1.0, 1.835)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPointF(1.0, 1.835)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPointF(1.0, 1.835)
PyQt5.QtCore.QPointF(1.0, 1.835)
```

как мне получить по отдельности то, что в круглых скобках?
Данные будут использоваться для PYQT5.

Comment: zn[0].x() и zn[0].y() если я правильно понял, что у вас в коде происходит

Comment: да, все верно цифра 1.0 это по оси x, а 1.835 по оси y. Спасибо, получилось можете ставить ответ, проголосую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `QPointF` доступ координаты точки доступны через методы `x()` и `y()`

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QPointF.html

```
x = zn[0].x()
y = zn[0].y()
```